# "Make homepage" missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages, homepage

In my SharePoint online site, I've created a page that I now want to make the homepage.

But when I right click on the page, I can't see the option Make Homepage.

Do you have any idea? (I have the admin rights for this group).

Comment: Is this modern site page? you have "owners" permissions on SharePoint site?

Comment: In addition to Ganesh, if you are using classic experience, you may not be able to find this option, you can convert to modern and follow the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created & published a new page in "Site Pages" library on SharePoint online site, follow below steps to make it as a home page:

1. Go to Site Pages library
2. Select the newly created site page
3. Select **Make homepage** from command bar at the top

[image]